# EF Attach won't update database fields to null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm facing a problem that when I set a field any value than empty, EF will update the database.

But, when I clear the field (input[text] empty), the matching field in DB won't update to NULL.

Here are the codes:

C#

```
var entidade = new Plantas { CodPlanta = vm.CodPlanta };
db.Plantas.Attach(entidade);

entidade.CodEstado = vm.CodEstado;
entidade.NomePlanta = vm.NomePlanta;
entidade.CEP = vm.CEP;
entidade.Telefone = vm.Telefone;
entidade.Fax = vm.Fax;

db.SaveChanges();
```

SQL generated by EF

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Plantas]
set [CodEstado] = @0, [NomePlanta] = @1, [CEP] = @3
where ([CodPlanta] = @4)
',N'@0 int,@1 varchar(200),@3 char(8),@4 int',
@0=26,
@1='Apiaí',
@2='Integrada',
@3='18320000',
@4=373
go
```

See that when `vm.Telefone` and `vm.Fax`, these fields won't show in UPDATE query. But if a put some value, they will.

Even if the fields have some value before.

If a put a breakpoint at `db.Savechanges()`, it will show `entidade.Telefone = null`. But it won't go to the generated query.

How can I force Entity Framework to set fields to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that setting attached instance of entity to "Modified" works:

```
db.Entry(entidade) = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that EF will only save modified fields. So if the field was null before you attach the object, and you set it to null again, EF will not update the database.

The solution is pretty simple: set the field to something other than null before you attach the object, than modify it to null before you save it.

One caveat: if you have optimistic concurrency control on the field, you may have to read the record from the database instead of attaching an empty object. Alternatively, use one column for optimistic concurrency control, such as a version number or SQL Server timestamp column.

For example, say you have this problem with the CEP column. Then do:

```
var entidade = new Plantas { CodPlanta = vm.CodPlanta };

entidade.CEP = "fake old value";

db.Plantas.Attach(entidade);

entidade.CEP = vm.CEP;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The field isn't null before the update, they have value and I set to null. So i'm changing the value.

Comment: The field isn't null in the database, but it is null in the object in memory that you attach. The object in memory isn't changed, so EF sees no reason to propagate a change to the database. EF has no way of knowing that the column contains something other than null in the database, because you have not told it. You could by reading instead of attaching, but that would be less efficient. Or you can fake it, as presented in my answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: ahhh ok! I've tried and it worked. I thought that "field null before" was to db field. But I have another question... is there a simple way? perhaps some property that forces all fields to be Modified State? because there're several fields, the code I posted was just a sample..

Comment: I don't know any other way (except for reading first of course, but that is inefficient).